# Adobe Indesign: Finding the last bullet in a bullet list

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, paragraph-styles, formatting

My current style sheet is:

- [Body] After paragraph : 4mm
- [Body, Start of List] After paragraph : 1mm
- [Bullets] After paragraph : 1mm
- [Bullets, Last] After paragraph : 4mm

### Part 1

Is there a way to Find the last bullet in a bullet list and then apply my  [Bullets, Last] style. (in Find and replace - styles)

### Part 2

Is there a way to Find the Paragraph before the Bullet list ?
So i can add in [Body, Start of List] to this paragraph.

Would this be a grep thing?

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1

There is no need to set a different style on the last bullet point.

Just set up "bullets" style with `Space after` set to 4mm and `Space between` set to 1mm, and apply this one style to all bullets.

### Part 2:

I know of no good way to find the para before a bullet list, but you can use a trick to apply 2 styles at once.

First the set up:

- You already have a "bullets" style.
- Then set up a "introducing bullets" style.
- Set the `Next style` of "introducing bullets" to your "bullets" style.

Then to apply:

- select the text that needs to be styled: from the introducing para, down to the last bullet point
- right click "introducing bullets" style in the paragraph styles panel, and choose `Apply "introducing bullets" then Next Style`

See the demo below.

[image: screencap using 3 styles]

### Bonus Part 3!

If you switch to using `space before`, you will only need to 2 styles: the body style with 4mm above, and the list style with 1mm above. You can ignore space between.

[image: screencap using only 2 styles]

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `Indents and Spacing` section of the `Paragraph Style` dialog to specify `Space Before` and `Space After`.
- Use the option `Space Between Paragraphs Using Same Style` to specify the space between the bulleted list items. (note: this is a new-ish feature and may not be available in older versions in InDesign)
- For example, if `Space Before` is 1mm, `Space After` is 2mm, and `Space Between` is 3mm, the bulleted list will have 1mm pt before the 1st item, 2mm after the last item and in between the bulleted list items, space will be 3mm.

[image]